# Using matlab and Time Series object (fints), how can I make an array of them?

Tags: matlab

I am getting stock prices from yahoo, and want to have each stock have its own time series data structure, but also don't want to have hundreds of variables, so naturally I would want to have an array, but when I do something like array = [stock1 stock2]; it actually merges the series together.  How can I make a real array?
Thanks,
CP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[x x]` notation in matlab is not an array, it is a vector.  It is assumed that what you're putting together belongs together.  What you probably want is a cell array which is indexed with a curly brace, ie `myArray{1} = stock1; myArray{2} = stock2;`.  Reference [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/06/21/cell-arrays-and-their-contents/).

Comment: This is the correct answer, fints objects have overridden the [] operator so that [stock1; stock2] doesn't work because it tries to merge them.  Thanks for informing me also about vector vs. cell array

Answer (score 0):

Ah, since you have row vectors, `[stock1 stock2]` is a concatenation. If you want to create a 2-by-x array instead, do something like this `[stock1; stock2]`, which will place one array above the other.

Answer (score 0):

Joining vectors using `[x y]` has different results depending on whether your vectors are rows or columns.  If rows, then joining them with `[x y]` makes a longer row vector, but if columns, you'll get a Nx2 matrix.  You should probably convert them to column vectors using the [TRANSPOSE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) operator thus: `[x' y']`.  Although you should check if transpose means the same thing with Time Series objects as at does with regular vectors.